# C# Expression while ((sLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)

Tags: c#

I have just come across this line of C# code and I am not sure what it means:

```
string sLine = "";

while ((sLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

I assume `oStreamReader.ReadLine()` is a string too.

My guess is that it is saying whilst neither of the variables are null?

I have searched around but have not been able to find any reference to this kind of notation

Comment: It is a loop ReadLine reads one line at a time so it reads lines one by one until file ends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My guess is that it is saying whilst neither of the variables are
>   null?

No it is not comparing both. Instead this line

```
while ((sLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

means,

1. Assign the result of `oStreamReader.ReadLine` to `sLine`
2. Check if the result of assignment expression is not equal to null. *(That result will be stored in `sLine`)*

Comment: damn, just beat me to it :)

Comment: I put comment instead ..:)

Answer (score 1):

It reads all the lines in the stream reader.

Parsing the expression, this is what happens:

1. `oStreamReader.ReadLine()` is executed
2. It's return value is assigned to `sLine`
3. The return value of the assignment is compared to `null`

It's not comparing `sLine` to null, and it's not comparing `oStreamReader.ReadLine()` to null either. If `sLine` was a property that only had a setter, it would still work fine.

The idea is that the assignment operator itself actually has a return value - and that's what's being compared to `null`.